# Django order queryset by time starting in a specific hour with sending other results at last

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following django query:

```
views.some_model.objects.all().order_by('start')
```

This works fine. The result comes like this:

```
{00:00, 00:30, 02:03, 04:00, 05:33}
```

What if I need it to start the `order_by` from a specific hour and sending the rest to the last (also ordered)? like this:

```
{02:03, 04:00, 05:33, 00:00, 00:30}
```

I know that I can make two queries (one starting from the time that I need, the other for the last part), but is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is to use two queries. But since you want to explore for an alternative, I came up with this really ugly looking query -

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField

qs = views.some_model.objects
           .annotate(
               recent=Case(
                   When(start__gt=some_date_var,
                        then=Value(1)),
                   default=Value(0),
                   output_field=IntegerField()))
           .order_by('-recent', 'start')
```

Basically first annotate with a boolean(which I called ***recent***) marking if the ***start*** is greater than ***some_date_var*** (1 meaning start is greater, 0 otherwise). Now order first by the ***recent*** descending, then by ***start*** ascending

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine two queries using [`union`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#union):

```
qs1 = views.some_model.objects.filter(start_gt=some_date_var).order_by('start')
qs2 = views.some_model.objects.all()
qs1.union(qs2)
```

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way to do it, and it works fine. But I wan't to know if there is a simplest way, without querying the database twice.

Comment: Tried. qs1.union(qs2) makes the union but disordered. It's not the solution. Thanks anyway.